# thunderbird.cfg trust ca root certificate

Tags: certificate-authority, thunderbird, autoconfiguration

We have just started using **Thunderbird autoconfiguration** and find it really useful for automatically creating the company standard imap, smtp and ldap accounts for every user that launches the mail client.

**However**, the company ldap server (actually, a Windows domain controller) uses a certificate issued by our company Certification Authority, which is of course not trusted by Thunderbird. As a consequence, the ldap remote address book does not syncronize until the ca certificate is manually imported and trusted.

Can the dear `thunderbird.cfg` be employed to import and trust a ca root?

We already tried the following [two solutions](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA:AddRootToFirefox), and they apparently did nothing: maybe they are only for Firefox, or are not being correctly configured on our part.

1. trying to trust ca roots trusted by the Windows operating system:

   ```
   pref("security.enterprise_roots.enabled, true");
   ```
2. trying to import and trust the ca root certificate:

   ```
   var Cc = Components.classes;
   var Ci = Components.interfaces;
   var certdb = Cc["@mozilla.org/security/x509certdb;1"].getService(Ci.nsIX509CertDB);
   var certdb2 = certdb;
   try {
      certdb2 = Cc["@mozilla.org/security/x509certdb;1"].getService(Ci.nsIX509CertDB2);
   } catch (e) {}
   // This should be the certificate content with no line breaks at all.
   cert = "MII ... ==";
   certdb.addCertFromBase64(cert, "C,C,C");
   ```

---

**Update**, and a solution.

We couldn't figure out method `1.`, but were successful in the end with method `2.` The mistake was my apparent misunderstanding of the sentence:

> the third parameter has been removed from the API and should not be
>   included

I thought `addCertFromBase64` needed only have two parameters, whereas it still requires a third parameter, even if it's only a blank string. Editing the command to `certdb.addCertFromBase64(cert, "C,C,C","");` did work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for method `2.`, a parameter is missing. The following code works (see the last  line):

```
var Cc = Components.classes;
var Ci = Components.interfaces;
var certdb = Cc["@mozilla.org/security/x509certdb;1"].getService(Ci.nsIX509CertDB);
var certdb2 = certdb;
try {
   certdb2 = Cc["@mozilla.org/security/x509certdb;1"].getService(Ci.nsIX509CertDB2);
} catch (e) {}
// This should be the certificate content with no line breaks at all.
cert = "MII ... ==";
certdb.addCertFromBase64(cert, "C,C,C","");
```